# javascript: input form requires specific word

Tags: javascript

i'm having a hard time validating a text field that must have a specific word in it. For example i have typed a test page that requires the user to type 'hello' if they don't there will be an alert.

I have tried using indexOf, but it fail to work in my case. May i ask what went wrong? and is there any other way of validating such scenario? I would prefer to use vanilla javascript if possible. Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkText()
            {
            var text1 = document.getElementById("intro").value;
            var text2 = 'hello';

            if(text1.indexOf(text2) > -1){
                alert("Say hello");
                return false;
            }else{
                alert("Okay!");
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Introduce yourself <input type="text" name="intro" id="intro"> <input type="button" value="Click" onClick="checkText()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Inline Method

---

You must get the value inside the function since it will not be available when the script is loaded.  Also if you want to alert `Say hello` when hello is not present, change the conditional to check for `text1.indexOf(test2) == -1`:

```
    var text2 = 'hello';

    function checkText()
    {
        var text1 = document.getElementById("intro").value;
        if(text1.indexOf(text2) == -1){
            alert("Say hello");
            return false;
        }else{
            alert("Hello " +text1);
        }
    }
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/J4eGw/

---

### Preferred Method

---

Another thing to note, you should avoid attaching events inline within the HTML.  You can use the following to attach the events within the script.

**HTML**

```
Introduce yourself <input type="text" name="intro" id="intro">
<input id="btnCheck" type="button" value="Click">
```

**Javascript**

```
 var text2 = 'hello';

addEvent(window, "load", function(){
   addEvent(document.getElementById("btnCheck"), "click", checkText);
});


function checkText()
{
    var text1 = document.getElementById("intro").value;
    alert((text1.toLowerCase().indexOf(text2) == -1) ? "Say hello":"Okay");
}

function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
    if (element.attachEvent){
       //for early IE versions
       return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
    }else{
       //for modern browsers
       return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
    }
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/J4eGw/2/

Comment: `text1.toLowerCase().indexOf(text2)`

Comment: @RendySetiadi Also consider the updated preferred method which attaches events via the script instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

`text1` isn't defined  to the latest value when you're checking it, so you should do this instead:

var text2 = 'hello';

```
        function checkText()
        {
            var text1 = document.getElementById("intro").value;//updates every time you check

            if(text1.indexOf(text2) > -1){
                alert("Say hello");
                return false;
            }else{
                alert("Hello " +text1);
             }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Introduce yourself <input type="text" name="intro" id="intro"> <input type="button" value="Click" onClick="checkText()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text2 = 'hello';
function checkText(){
        text1 = document.getElementById("intro").value;
        if(text1.indexOf(text2) > -1){
            alert("Say hello");
            return false;
        } else {
        alert("Hello " +text1);
    }   
}
<
```

You will need to ensure that the new value of text1 is obtained on each click, not just when the script loads.